# Round value in dictionary to nearest 5 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, rounding

I want to round to the nearest 5 an element in the value of a dictionary.

Given a dictionary:

```
d = {'0': '0 43 1000 27 3 I', '1': '2 52 1020 28 3 J', '2': '2 11 10 281 32 T'}
```

I want to return the second element in the value of each dict, and round it to the nearest 5. So round 43 to 45, 52 to 50 and 11 to 10.

So far I only know how to return the value of a key in the dict,

```
for i in d['0']
```

but cant figure out the rest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should not you want 11 to 10? Can you also post an expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To round to nearest 5, you can use a custom function:

```
def round_five(x):
    return 5 * round(x/5)
```

To access the second number in your `string` of numbers:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    # make a list out of the string
    nums = v.split(" ") 

    # round the 2nd element
    rounded = round_five(nums[1])

    # do something with the second element:
    print(rounded)
```

Comment: May the heavens bless your soul. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `round` function in any case, the other way around by breaking the `round` function itself is this:

```
def doit(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
    nums = value.split(" ")
    if int(nums[1])%5>=3:
        print((int(nums[1])//5)*5+5)
    else:
        print((int(nums[1])//5)*5)
```

Thanks.